# SONAR - Migration from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sonarqube

Can anyone help me in finding answers for below two questions:

1. **Can we use MS SQL Server 2012 for SONAR?**

   As per latest document, SQL Server 2008 is supported, but There is no much information about 2012.
2. **How we can maintain History in Database Migration?**

   In my case, We are using MySQL for a long time and interested in SQL Server along with SONAR latest Upgrade. I am not sure how we can Import the data from MySQL to SQL Server to maintain history of existing projects.

   Please share your views.

-Ankit

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 2012 is not supported because there's no integration test on this platform. So, it's at your own risk. There's currently no way to migrate data from one database to another.